# How to create Aging dashboard using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dashboard

I have below data frame of item with expiry date:

```
Item          Expiry Date   Stock
Voucher 1     1-Mar-2022     3
Voucher 2     31-Apr-2022    2
Voucher 3     1-Feb-2022     1
```

And I want to create an aging dashboard and map out my number of stock there:

```
           Jan Feb Mar Apr
Voucher 1           3
Voucher 2               2
Voucher 3        1
```

Any ideas or guides how to do something like above please? I searched a lot of resources, cannot find any. I'm very new on building dashboards. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the month name (*NB. Your dates are invalid. 31 Apr. is impossible*) and `pivot` the table. If needed, `reindex` with a list of months names:

```
from calendar import month_abbr
cols = month_abbr[1:] # first item is empty string

(df.assign(month=df['Expiry Date'].str.extract('-(\D+)-'))
   .pivot(index='Item', columns='month', values='Stock')
   .reindex(columns=cols)
 )
```

**If you expect to have duplicated Items, use `pivot_table` with `sum` as aggregation function instead**

Output:

```
month      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
Item                                                                 
Voucher 1  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Voucher 2  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Voucher 3  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It's the OP to be primarily concerned about. They don't even share a single line of code of attempt, and they are expected to copy-paste this. what does assign do? what is that weird thing in str.extract? etc. Now you can say "if they have query, they should ask" and "I ain't no documentation" (you already implied the latter for example); but a line of comment of what it is doing is what I mean, like the other answer has. Again, my definition of wrongness.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Item          Expiry Date   Stock
# Voucher 1     1-Mar-2022     3
# Voucher 2     31-Apr-2022    2
# Voucher 3     1-Feb-2022     1

data = {'Item': ['Voucher 1', 'Voucher 2', 'Voucher 3'],
        'Expiry Date': ['1-Mar-2022', '31-Apr-2022', '1-Feb-2022'],
        'Stock': [3, 2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Using pandas apply method, get the month from each row using axis=1 and store it in new column 'Month'
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
df['Month'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Expiry Date'].split('-')[1], axis=1)

# Using pandas pivot method, set 'Item' column as index,
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html
# set unique values in 'Month' column as separate columns
# set values in 'Stock' column as values for respective month columns
# and using 'rename_axis' method, remove the row name 'Month'
# https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html
new_df = df.pivot(index='Item', columns='Month', values='Stock').rename_axis(None, axis=1)

# Sort the month column names by first converting it to the the pandas timestamp object 
# then using it as a key in a sorted function on all columns
new_df = new_df[sorted(new_df.columns, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b'))]

print(new_df)
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
           Feb  Mar  Apr
Item                    
Voucher 1  NaN  3.0  NaN
Voucher 2  NaN  NaN  2.0
Voucher 3  1.0  NaN  NaN
```